# Remote Access to a computer that is behind a proxy?

Tags: remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remote into Linux workstation behind a firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/274221/remote-into-linux-workstation-behind-a-firewall)

I want to access a computer in location `A` that is behind a proxy server. I do not have administrator access to the router at this location (so I can't forward ports to this location). Is there any way to access this computer from another location `B`? By access I mean any form of access : Remote access or SSH or any other way.

Comment: Depends on what ports are open through the proxy...

Answer (score 3):

[Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx) uses a relay to get around this. You may also want to look into other programs that do this, such as [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/), [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/), and [Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/overview/).

Comment: +1 for logmein, I have used their service for a while and have no complaints.

Comment: How do I identify this computer in location `A` from location `B`. It does not have a public IP. I think it is behind a NAT server

Comment: These options usually associate your computer with an account or provided URL. For example, teamviewer gives you a nine digit ID and a four-digit PIN to log in with.