# Persistent outgoing connection from firewalled Linux box

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, cron

There's a great method to allowing one to access a machine behind a firewall by creating an outgoing listening connection:
[Remote into Linux workstation behind a firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/274221/remote-into-linux-workstation-behind-a-firewall)

My question is, what's the best way to make sure this connection is always up in a safe manner  when I'm not at the desk? cron? (Reboots, power outage, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the SSH method from the accepted answer?  The OpenVPN answer would be far more stable, since it is designed to function as a VPN, packaged versions of OpenVPN include startup scripts, and the OpenVPN daemon is very good about resuming a connection after a restart.

Anyway, assuming the SSH solution, you should really be taking a strong look at the [autossh](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) program.  It is specifically design for the purpose of bringing up SSH port forwards automatically and reliably.