# Remote into Linux workstation behind a firewall using NoMachine or other remote desktop service

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, nx

My question is very similar to this question: [Remote into Linux workstation behind a firewall](https://superuser.com/questions/274221/remote-into-linux-workstation-behind-a-firewall)

My work has firewall and ssh server.  The ssh server is listening to the default port 22.  Normally I don't require a GUI so I just ssh into the ssh server from a home computer (MacBook) and then ssh into my personal work computer (Ubuntu 14.04) on the lan.

Normal Steps:

```
ssh me@workSSHServer
ssh me@myPersonalWorkComputer #on the workSSHServer
```

Now I would like to access my work computer (running Ubuntu 14.04) from my personal computer on my home network using a GUI.  I thought I did everything right using NoMachine but I think I need some pointers.

NoMachine Service (a remote desktop service) is running on my personal work computer on port 4001.  (I don't anything when I run `netstat -na | grep 4001` though)

I did ssh port forwarding on my MacBook (home computer):

```
ssh -L 4001:myPersonalWorkComputer:22 me@workSSHServer
```

I thought I just be able to use the No Machine client on my MacBook to remote into localhost:4001 and get redirected to my personal work computer but it isn't work.  Sorry I'm not super experienced here.  Let me know if I can give anyone any more context/information.  Am I trying something fundamentally impossible?  Taking a completely wrong approach?  Missing some small details?

Configuration on my MacBook:
[image: MacBook - NoMachine client configuration]
[image: MacBook - NoMachine client error]

Results of `vim /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg` on my personal work computer:
[image: vim /usr/NX/etc/server.cfg]

Comment: I change the protocol on myPersonalWork computer to SSH and I'm getting this warning: "Running NoMachine sessions over a SSH connection is not supported on this server. Do you want to switch your connection to using the NX protocol?"  and then "Error is 61: Connection refused"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ssh command is wrong. Try this instead:

```
ssh -L 4001:myPersonalWorkComputer:4001 me@workSSHServer
```

You may want to make sure that "myPersonalWorrkComputer" is set to the internal LAN IP of your work computer.

Answer (score 1):

The free version doesn't support SSH so you should use the instructions provided on the NoMachine website to know how to tunnel NX over an SSH connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use X11 forwarding over SSH:

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html
https://askubuntu.com/questions/35512/what-is-the-difference-between-ssh-y-trusted-x11-forwarding-and-ssh-x-u

It should work even through chained tunnels, if you use -Y with each command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try their website?

https://www.nomachine.com/AR10K00728
Connecting by SSH to a NoMachine host in version 4

Comment: While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.